# IOS use inherited View inside interface builder

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiimageview, interface-builder

I've extended UIImageView inorder to create a rounder image view:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "RoundedImageView.h"
@implementation RoundedImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self makeImageViewRounded];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) makeImageViewRounded {
    self.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius=20;
    self.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
}


/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

In the story board i've connected an UIImageView to my custom RoundedImageView,
But it doesn't seems to affect the view, and my code doesn't get called.

[image: storyboard]

How can i make it work that whenever i attach an custom view to my UIView, the custom view will be initialised ?

Comment: That is because the "initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)aDecoder" initializer will be called.

Comment: amazing! write it as an answer so i could accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override this initializer when creating views from storyboard:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        [self makeImageViewRounded];
    }

    return self;
}
```